# What is the meaning of scalar here in php

Tags: php

Hello everyone I am net developer.Now I am learning PHP. I am studying about the php objects and I try this code

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$obj=(object)'ciao';
echo $obj->scalar;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I want to know what is the scalar exactly? Why We are using it here?

Comment: I think this question is more meant to be: "What is a *scalar* in general that it is named this way in this situation?". Am I right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ### Converting to object
>
> If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value
> of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the
> stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new
> instance will be empty. Arrays convert to an object with properties
> named by keys, and corresponding values. **For any other value, a member
> variable named scalar will contain the value.**
>
> ```
> <?php
> $obj = (object) 'ciao';
> echo $obj->scalar;  // outputs 'ciao'
> ?>
> ```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: okk means scalar is a system defined variable which hold the value of an object am i right????

Comment: It's a member variable of the object, just as the manual says.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting here `ciao` to an `object`. When you do `echo $obj->scalar;` you will get output as `ciao`. Since scalar is the member variable which contains that value.
For more details please see this link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php